# JQuery divs with collapsible function. Close all other divs when clicking div to expand

Tags: jquery, html

JQuery div with collapsible function. Close all other `div` when clicking `div` to expand.

Example code below:

```
<div data-role="collapsible" id="1">
  <h4><span>text</span></h4>
  <ul data-role="listview">
      <li>text</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div data-role="collapsible" id="2">
    <h4><span>text</span></h4>
    <ul data-role="listview">
        <li>text</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div data-role="collapsible" id="3">
  <h4><span>text</span></h4>
  <ul data-role="listview">
      <li>text</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

So if I click `div` with id 1, other `div` retract and `div` 1 extends, and when I click example `div` with id 3, other `div` retract and `div` 3 extends.

Comment: Can you add any jQuery code you used in your example? Always try to provide as much information as possible in your question

Comment: i have included following libraries to had section: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="cssimgfiles/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
<script src="cssimgfiles/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="cssimgfiles/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>       so i havent needed to code any script yet.